# In Linux system file extensions as capital and small lettters

Tags: linux, file, file-extension

While using linux system I encounter that that many file extensions are in capital as well as small letters like
`myfile.JPG` and `myfile.jpg`

I know Linux file system is case sensitive, but what's the difference in these two files? and why sometimes they get saved saved as capital or sometimes in small.

I have seen the same for other file too like
`.ttf` vs `.TTF`

Thanks
[image]

Comment: In one case Shift was held or Caps Lock was enabled when the extension was typed, and not with the other.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/158110/does-linux-support-images-in-jpeg-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference if you name the file `myfile.jpg` or `myfile.JPG` or `myfile.jpeg`. Linux doesn't care.

The extension might be used by some programs running on linux and by humans to easily identify the filetype but it doen't affects the file in any way. You can even call it `myfile.dog` or just leave it without extension and would be the same image file and for linux it wouldn't make any difference.

If you have an image file and you want to tell what kind of image file it is you can use the `file` command or if you have imagemagick installed you can use the `identify` command.

Try renaming some jpeg file and give it a png extension, the run `file image.png`, you will see that it still is a jpeg file and that the png extension is there only to confuse you.

You might find this usefull: https://www.quora.com/How-do-Linux-identify-file-types-without-extensions-And-why-cant-Windows-do-so